# How would I apply a custom query to a Doctrine entity in Symfony2, using just annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entities

How would I apply a custom query to a Doctrine entity in Symfony2, using just annotations?

For example:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="some_object")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class SomeObject
{
    /**
     * @ORM\SomeSpecialQuery()
     */
    private $someSpecialResult;
}
```

`$someSpecialResult` should contain the results of the special query when used. The attribute should be container aware preferably so that existing repository functions can be called if desired. A typical query could be `SELECT x FROM SomeBundle:EntityName x WHERE x.someOtherValue = null LIMIT 5`.

My question has come around because I have an entity that I would like to always have access to certain related information (which is much faster to perform as a custom DQL query).

As an added bonus, it would be great if it could be lazy-loaded? Obviously, if there's a better way to do this I am happy to hear it! Thanks.

Comment: have you thought about lazy loading this in a getter?